# How can I get a ScrollView with centered content and a footer?

Tags: android, scrollview, android-linearlayout

i am trying to achieve the following in one of my layouts for my android app:

I would like to have a layout that holds the main content (linearlayout with other content) and a footer (linear layout with other content). The main content should be centered both horizontally and vertically. The footer should just be centered horizontally and always stay at the bottom.

In addition to that, the main content and the footer should be wrapped in a scrollview because it is possible that the main content grows and all the content should stil be accessible.

How can I do that?

Comment: @user2426316 was the answer below anywhere near what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

I think the following gets close to what you want with the assumption that when you wrote 'The footer should just be centered horizontally and always stay at the bottom.' you meant the bottom of the screen.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>
<ScrollView 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/footer" >
    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"            
        >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"    
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"            
            android:orientation="vertical" >
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"    
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:minLines="0"
                android:visibility="invisible"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/body"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="My main body text to display"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"    
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:minLines="0"
                android:visibility="invisible"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>     
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/footer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="My footer text to display"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Assuming this isn't quite right it should hopefully at least give you some ideas.